# Problem with binary search implementation

Tags: python, algorithm

I was solving a pretty simple problem.

> You get 3 numbers to input - a, b, c
> a - number of 2s
> b - number of 3s
> c - number of 4s.
> Those numbers represent marks that a student got for some subject.
> You need to print out how many 5s student should get so that their average outcome for the subject will be at least 4 (if average is not integer, it rounds up to closest integer number: 3.5 -> 4, 3.4 -> 3).
> Restrictions: 0 <= a, b, c <= 10**15, a + b + c >= 1.

My solution:

```
def main():
    a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
    l = 0
    r = a + b + c + 1
    if (2*a + 3*b + 4*c)/(a + b + c) >= 3.5:
        print(0)
        return
    
    while l <= r:
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        if (2*a+3*b+4*c+5*mid)/(a+b+c+mid) >= 3.5:
            r = mid - 1
        else:
            l = mid + 1

    print(l)

main()
```

I have passed 31/32 tests. [Rounding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgmC.png)

Comment: Binary search is used for searching sorted data. What does it have to do with this problem? It seems like it can be solved purely mathematically.

Comment: It's high school algebra: `3.5 <= 2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*x` Given `a, b, c`, solve for `x`.

Comment: @Barmar Binary search can be a perfectly fine solution for stuff like this. How do you think they passed 31/32 tests if it didn't have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: What precisely is the intended meaning of `l` and `r`?

Comment: @Barmar Your high school doesn't know how to compute an average.

Comment: @kelly, binary search is the incorrect method since it requires a list to search through. Other mathematics are more appropriate. so why are you persisting ?

Comment: @D.L It's not incorrect.

Comment: @KellyBundy,   see this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @D.L What about it?

Comment: @KellyBundy,  if you really insist that the problem is solvable with a binary search, then show it. otherwise be quiet.

Comment: @D.L I might fix theirs. After they answer my question. Again: 31 out of 32 correct already. You don't get that if it's nonsense. They just have a bug. Your current attempt won't even pass that many tests, far too slow.

Comment: you have spoken, made false claims and assertions and **provided no working solution of your own** whatsoever.  And certainly no solution with a binary search.

Comment: @D.L What false claims/assertions? I do *have* a working solution, btw, but it's a math one (takes 10 characters without the spaces), so I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: _"I do have a working solution"_ . . . so show it.

Comment: @D.L Why? Again, I don't think it answers the question. Since I don't think they're asking for alternative solutions but about their binary search attempt. (Correction: I need 17 characters, overlooked the possibility that the average is already enough, so need `max(` `,0)` around it.)

Comment: @perfect05 What *is* your question? You didn't actually ask any.

Comment: @KellyBundy _"I don't think it answers the question"_ . . . so you don't have a solution (as expected).

Comment: @D.L I do. A solution for the task. Not an answer for their "question". Which, as I said, I believe is about their attempt, so my math solution wouldn't answer it.

Comment: perfecto5, assuming you are still alive (which is in question since you have not answered any of the myraid questions asking for clarification in the comments above), is my understand of the question, as set forth in my answer, correct? If so, I could help clarify your question so that it might be reopened.

Comment: @CarySwoveland While they didn't explicitly ask a question, the title is *"Problem with binary search implementation"*, not something like *"How many 5s does the student need?"*, making their implementation the topic of the question, and the task they're trying to solve is just background. Any answer should address their implementation (what its problem is and how to fix it).

Comment: @Kelly, I could not disagree more. An answer to a question that presents a superior algorithm does no harm but only good (such as when the question presents an [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=xy+problem&oq=xy+proble&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqDAgAEAAYQxiABBiKBTIMCAAQABhDGIAEGIoFMgYIARBFGDkyDAgCEAAYQxiABBiKBTIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIMCAUQABgUGIcCGIAEMggIBhAAGBYYHjIICAcQABgWGB4yCggIEAAYDxgWGB4yCggJEAAYDxgWGB7SAQg5MjY5ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))...

Comment: ...I am reminded of the famous [fly problem](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1866783) that John Von Neuman solved in an instant by summing an infinite series. Would he not have wanted to be told the far simpler way of solving the problem?

Comment: @CarySwoveland And the analogy would be that Johnny asked something like *"Problem with my calculus"*, showing his solving method and reporting that it's not quite correct. Then it's ok to tell him the simpler way, but you should really show him the error in his calculus and how to fix it first.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you miss my point. If six people in the room explain to little Johnny where he went wrong, and how his calculations can be fixed, what's the problem with person #7--call them 007--saying, "Hey, Johnny, here's an easier way to to solving that problem...". Johnny may be interested in what 007 has said, but even he isn't someone else in the room might have learned something useful. Regardless, Johnny's got the answer to his question and someone may have been pleased that 007 spoke out.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're completely misrepresenting our situation. We don't have six answers explaining to the OP where they went wrong and how their code can be fixed. We have **zero** such answers. We only have three answers completely **ignoring** the OP's code (except for one wrongly dismissing binary search). Btw, "easier"? I'd say my `(0..10**16).bsearch { |x| Rational(2*a+3*b+4*c+5*x, a+b+c+x) >= 3.5}` is easier than yours. I just dumped the average calculation in there, didn't need math like yours. (Although I did some earlier to get my `max(a - (c - b) // 3, 0)` solution.)

Comment: @Kelly, I don't know Python so I am not qualified to fix the OP's code, but I could suggest a different algorithm. I see you are an experienced in Python. If you are dissatisfied with the other answers why not post one yourself?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm waiting for the OP's response. Plus the question is closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that we wish to compute the smallest non-negative integral value of `x` for which:

```
(2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*x)/(a + b + c + x) >= 3.5
```

We can manipulate this expression as follows:

```
(4*a + 6*b + 8*c + 10*x)/(a + b + c + x) >= 7
4*a + 6*b + 8*c + 10*x >= 7*a + 7*b + 7*c + 7*x
3*x >= y
```

where:

```
y = 3*a + b - c
```

If `y <= 0` then `x = 0`.

Now consider the case where `y > 0`.

Compute (in pseudo-code)

```
m = y.modulo(3)
```

which employs integer arithmetic.

Then

```
if m == 0
  x = y/3
else if m == 1
  x = (y+2)/3
else # m == 2
  x = (y+1)/3
```

In calculating `x` the numerator is known to equal a product of `3` so there is no remainder when dividing it by `3`, so integer arithmetic can be used.

As `0 <= a, b, c <= 10**15`, `y <= 10**16`, Python is easily able to accommodate the integer arithmethic calculations.

---

Consider an example using pseudo-code (in fact, Ruby).

```
a = 123456789012345
b = 234567890123456
c = 345678901234568
```

then

```
y = 3*a + b - c
  #=> 259259355925923
```

`y` modulo `3` is found to equal:

```
m = y % 3
  #=> 0
```

So

```
x = y/3
  #=> 86419785308641
```

where `y` is known to be a multiple of `3` so there is no remainder, meaning integer division can be employed.

As a check (not a test)

```
(2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*x)/(a + b + c + x).to_f
  #=> 3.5
```

Comment: Your result 316872386131687 is wrong. Rather obviously so, if you just look at it along with the three input numbers and observe that there are more 5s than 2s and more 4s than 3s, so the average is clearly above 3.5. Ruby's binary search btw makes it really nice and easy: `(0..10**16).bsearch { |x| Rational(2*a+3*b+4*c+5*x, a+b+c+x) >= 3.5}` (not extensively tested and I rarely use Ruby, but gets the correct result for your example).

Comment: @Kelly, thanks for spotting that. The derivation was correct. I made a mistake in my example calculation, which I've fixed.

Comment: You could btw do `x = [a - (c - b) / 3, 0].max` (is there a better way to turn negatives into zero? Ruby has so many unusual things that I wouldn't be surprised.)

Comment: @Kelly, yes, that's how Ruby converts  negatives to zero, but `x = [a - (c - b))/ 3, 0].max` is only for the case where `(a - (c - b)).modulo(3)` equals zero. (More commonly, that's written `(a - (c - b)) % 3`).

Comment: No, it's for all cases. And I found `(a - (c - b) / 3).clamp(0..)` now (not sure I like it better).

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something?

```
 (2a + 3b + 4c + 5x) / (a + b + c + x) = 4
 2a + 3b + 4c + 5x = 4a + 4b + 4c + 4x
 x = 2a + b
```

No loops needed.

(I think you're overthinking it. The problem statement says: "how many 5s student should get so that their average outcome for the subject will be at least 4" and that simple math gives the answer: "For the average to be exactly 4, add twice as many fives as there are twos, and the same number as there are threes". "exactly 4" qualifies as "at least 4", doesn't it?)

(Just not to leave this unanswered)

The solution for the above equation for an arbitrary limit `N < 5` is

```
x = (N(a + b + c) - (2a + 3b + 4c)) / (5 - N)
```

let `N = p/q`, then

```
x = (p(a + b + c) - q(2a + 3b + 4c)) / (5q - p)
```

Since we're only interested in positive integer solutions, the answer would be `max(0, ceil(x))`, and the function is:

```
def solve(a, b, c, p, q):
    n = p * (a + b + c) - q * (2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c)
    d = 5 * q - p
    s = n // d
    return max(0, s if s * d == n else s + 1)
```

Demo:

```
import random

p = 7
q = 2

for _ in range(1000):

    a = random.randint(0, 10 ** 15)
    b = random.randint(0, 10 ** 15)
    c = random.randint(0, 10 ** 15)

    x = solve(a, b, c, p, q)
    if x <= 0:
        continue

    y = x - 1

    curr_n = 2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c + 5 * x
    curr_d = a + b + c + x
    prev_n = 2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c + 5 * y
    prev_d = a + b + c + y

    print('{:20d}, {:20d}, {:20d} => {:20d} {:.20f} <-> {:.20f}'.format(
        a, b, c, x, prev_n / prev_d, curr_n / curr_d))

    # prove that our `x` is indeed the minimum

    assert q * curr_n >= p * curr_d
    assert q * prev_n < p * prev_d
```

This should print something like

```
 925175959795489,      572467880913462,      585062788264521 =>      920977657345136 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 372217497010590,      179184732304195,       41649869389423 =>      418062451315514 3.49999999999999866773 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 308865190673002,      641835477313737,      856332011403654 =>      237366345976363 3.49999999999999911182 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 563889890540176,       67029875689336,      596607063344755 =>      387364161321703 3.49999999999999911182 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 570247179872699,      991208015257768,      162497705434570 =>      846483949813765 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 453789123511666,       70082466984924,      593871458522635 =>      279192792999096 3.49999999999999911182 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 157555090291705,       23530910077091,       67073518274690 =>      143040887559172 3.49999999999999600320 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 820823944147388,      606060897075689,      211640336873851 =>      952297464214668 3.50000000000000000000 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 337173451306271,      680713356289187,      872455141589071 =>      273259522872977 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 973271444184488,      142533807164589,      951800602792647 =>      703515845641802 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000000000
 190059708028198,      864637147465976,      220368732192751 =>      404815846452607 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 862189619271235,      341038692404707,      450548848046157 =>      825686234057419 3.50000000000000000000 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 539977927109838,      738835277740343,      109903295051731 =>      749621921339376 3.49999999999999955591 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
 589211823866866,       16617596098774,      135290877264470 =>      549654063478301 3.49999999999999911182 <-> 3.50000000000000044409
```

Notice the rows with `3.50...` is the 5th column - these quotients are actually less than `3.5`, they simply don't fit in the floating point precision. Every solution that uses floating point will be off by 1 in these cases.

Comment: You're missing the rounding.

Comment: @KellyBundy: could you elaborate how exactly "rounding" is involved in computing "x = 2a + b"?

Comment: The rounding from the task, which means that you just need 3.5 (as the OP already realized, you can see it in their code).

Comment: Hmm, why double down on your mistake instead of fixing it?

Comment: Is your argument that the task doesn't say something like *"how many 5s student **needs**"*? If you're not minimizing the number, then you might as well just print `10**16` every time, rendering the challenge rather meaningless.

Comment: @KellyBundy: whoever designed that exercise was either confused themselves or intentionally added that rounding bullshit in order to confuse students.  If the latter, they succeeded, as this very thread proves ;)

Comment: I don't think it's confusing, you just ignored it. That's not *their* fault.

Comment: No, you're not missing anything, so long as you've interpreted the question correctly. I had a different interpretation but the wording of the question seems to conflict with both. Moreover, we may never know what is being asked as the OP seems to have flown the coop. Nor may we ever know if the OP was wed to a solution that employed a binary search or if they just wanted a solution and a binary search is all they could think of.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, the question is written in a very ambiguous way, intentionally or not, but the solution stands: solve the equation for the given limit value (4 or 3 1/2, doesn't matter), do some rational arithmetics and ceil the result. No rounding or floating point approximation involved. That's essentially what you did in your post, too bad the OP choose to disappear from the horizon without giving us any feedback.

Comment: *"Every solution that uses floating point will be off by 1 in these cases."* - I tried the first of these cases with `math.ceil(a+b/3-c/3)` and got the correct result 952297464214668, not off by 1.

Answer (score -3):

this is a relatively straight forward problem with a bit of error checking.

the question makes a good effort, but overcomplicates the mathematics. here is a solution that starts at zero and keeps guessing by adding 1 (you can optimise this).

FYI: binary search requires an **initial list** to do a search on (see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is not required here, so the question is misleading.

The problem would also require that the average < 5 (the max score) otherwise the problem would never converge.

a solution looks like this:

```py
def main():
    ''' main entry point for the code '''
    a, b, c = 1 ,2 ,3
    avg = 4.5
    result = how_many_fives(a,b,c, avg)
    print(result)



def how_many_fives(a:int, b:int, c:int, avg:float)->int:
    """
    given a, b, c and the average, return x
    """
    # check that a, b, c are all > 0
    if a < 0: raise ValueError('a must be >= 0')
    if b < 0: raise ValueError('b must be >= 0')
    if c < 0: raise ValueError('c must be >= 0')

    # check that a, b, c are all <= 10**15
    if a > 10**15: raise ValueError('a is to big, 10**15')
    if b > 10**15: raise ValueError('b is to big, 10**15')
    if c > 10**15: raise ValueError('c is to big, 10**15')

    # check that a + b + c >= 1
    if a + b + c < 1: raise ValueError('expect a + b + c >= 1')

    # check that avg <= 5
    if avg > 5: raise ValueError('the solution will never converge')

    # initial guess
    x = 0
    average = (2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*x) / (a + b + c + x)

    # keep guessing
    while average < avg:
        x = x + 1
        average = round((2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*x) / (a + b + c + x))

    return x



# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The example above returns `15`.

Comment: @D.L It's btw funny... Your current code attempts different x-values, checking whether they're enough, and adjusting x accordingly, until you found the sweet spot. That's exactly what the OP's binary search does, except that's far more efficient.

Comment: @KellyBundy,  the code in the answer does not perform a binary search. it is a simple upward iteration.  `x = x + 1` inside a `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, I know. Not sure why you're telling me that.

Comment: Btw what do you have in mind with "you can optimise this"?